# Can I use async await without .then?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm a bit confused about the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) of `async await`. These docs use the `.then()` syntax to respond when an `async` function has resolved:

**mdn example**

```
async function add() {
  const b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30); // timer
  return b;
}
add().then(v => {
  console.log(v);  
});
```

But in my own code, I don't use `.then()` and it still works asynchronously. The flow is not blocked. So why would you use `.then()` ?

**async code without .then**

```
function start(){
    console.log("starting!")
    let d = loadData()
    console.log("this message logs before loadData returns!")
    console.log(d)   // this shows: Promise - Pending because d has not yet returned
}
async function loadData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/films/");
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log("data loaded!")
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried throttling your connection to see if it's not an unfulfilled race condition?

Comment: What if you want to use `json`, or ensure a piece of code runs as soon as `loadData` finishes? That's when you'd use `then`.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If you want the promise to work with, use the direct return from `loadData()`. If you want the json result, you'll need `.then` or something similar.

Comment: I was hoping to bind `d` directly to a Vue property (filling the UI when `d` returns), but apparently `d` is a Promise, so I still have to use `.then()` to get the contents of `d`. I was hoping this wouldn't be necessary!

Comment: Which begs the question of what `await` buys you if you still have to use `.then`. Short answer is that it cuts down on lengthy Promise chains while allowing you to keep functions simple for testing etc.

Comment: @Kokodoko no, it can't affect anything outside it's scope (like a calling function). But if you call `loadData` inside another `async` function you can `await` it. It's still just sugar over Promises.

Comment: @JaredSmith exactly! I was hoping that `async await` would completely get rid of promises but sadly it's only a very slightly different way of writing. You might say that `async await` itself is an... unfulfilled promise... sorry... :)

Comment: @Kokodoko yeah, you can't really sweep the concurrency issue under the rug. Promises (and similar constructs like Futures and Observables) are here to stay. Arguably the best part of `async/await` is that you get `try/catch` back.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, all async functions return a Promise, so if you want to get the returned value from that async operation, you'll either need to use `then` or `await` inside an async function.

MDN uses `.then` because the `add` async function is being called outside an async function scope, so it can't use `await` globally to catch the data from the promise.

In your example, you get the same, an instance of Promise as the return of your `loadData` async function, if you define the `start` function also as async, you can use `let d = await loadData()`, if it's not async, you can use `.then` (which is the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)).

Comment: If I try `let d = await loadData()` then I get the error 'await expression is only allowed within an async function`... :'-(

Comment: that's why I mentioned:

> **if you define the start function also as async,** you can use `let d = await loadData()`

:)

Comment: Thanks! That works :) If I put `console.log(d)` on the next line, is that async as well? - or do I need to use `await console.log(d)` ?

Comment: Don't worry, all lines from inside your start function that comes after your `let d = await loadData()` will be executed only when your async operation (`loadData`) is finished and your variable `d` got the returned value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Async function declaration `async function loadData()` returns `AsyncFunction` which is executed asynchronously and always returns a `Promise`.

Basically all the code you put inside the `async function someFunctionName` will be executed inside that `Promise` and when you `return` some value inside that function – it will resolve that promise.

So that `then()` call is to get the actual value from that `Promise` that your function returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works because it is not returning promise object and actually waiting for the response. It returns the json at the end. So, execution holds till it gets the response.

If your function is async you don't need to return promise, your return statement will wait for all 'await' statement before it to complete.

Comment: That's not true, execution continues beyond `d = loadData()`, as you can see in my log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your own code works, because you replaced the usage of `.then()` with the usage of `async await`.